# Laravel 5 - global exception handler for API requesting non-exist object

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3. I have few APIs where user will request for specific id. 
For example url to subscribe an event
`example.com/api/event/{id}/subscribe`

Normally if `id` not exist, Laravel will return response 500 with error message "Trying to get property of non-object"

So I would add check if event is exist like below in every controller where model 'id' id passed:

```
$event = Event::find($id)
if ($event) {
    // return json data
}
else {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'object not found'
    ], 404);
}
```

My question is, any better solution to handle this globally to check if object requested is not exist? My current solution is here, but I might think there should be better one

I add this code into my `app/Exception/Handler.php`, so every api request non-existing object will return 404 with specific json message. So the API consumer will know the object id not valid.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // global exception handler if api request for non existing object id
    if ($request->wantsJson() && $exception->getMessage() == 'Trying to get property of non-object') {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'object requested not found'
        ], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `render()` function of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class as:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->wantsJson() && $exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'object requested not found'], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

And remember to add following code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler)

Comment: `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;` do the trick. Thanks. also I change a bit your code to use `wantsJson()`

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your

```
$event = Event::find($id)
```

to

```
$event = Event::findOrFail($id)
```

As far I remember, it'll throw a `ModelNotFoundException` if it couldn't find anything for that id. Go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and inside the render method, catch the exception and handle it.

Edited:

```
if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        } elseif ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            $e = new HttpException(403, $e->getMessage());
        } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException && $e->getResponse()) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        }
```

You can see that the parent render method fires a `NotFoundHttpException` if it gets a `ModelNotFoundException` exception. I guess you can overwrite it to match your requirement.

Comment: `findOrFail` is good but it return NotFoundHttpException and I could check it when using your condition above and also when i cannot check using `if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)`. Thanks

Comment: @h44f33z `findOrFail` actually returns a `ModelNotFoundException ` but the parent render method fires an `NotFoundHttpException `. You can change that to match you requirement.

Comment: i see, but `if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)` also not match.

Comment: Hmm. can you try the below code,
`try
{
   $event = Event::findOrFail($id)
}

catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{   
    dd('model not found');
}`

Don't forget to import `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;` on top.